# como tener un boton solo, que haga put o post dependiendo si existe el registro o no??? laravel

Tags: laravel, botón

Mi idea es hacer un solo boton para un formulario y que sea un put o un post dependiendo que necesite, no se me ocurre como hacer. estoy trabajando en laravel

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Haz que tu pregunta [no parezca un ticket para el área de desarrollo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433). Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no depende tanto del botón si no del formulario, entonces debes tener una variable que te permita saber si se esta editando o por el contrario si lo que se esta haciendo es creando, de este modo cambias la ruta y el método.

Así:

```
@if(isset($user))
    {{Form::open(['route' => ['users.update',$user->id]])}}
    @method('PUT')
@else
    {{Form::open(['route' => ['users.store']])}}
@endif
```